# Response read timeout issue for Rest API when deployed on PCF

Tags: rest, jersey, rx-java, cloud-foundry

I am facing a strange issue where I have two rest api developed api A and api B.
API A is integrated with API B i.e. calls a API B providing appropriate requests, API B does some processing and sends back response to API A.  Given flow works fine when I test it by running both the api's locally.  But, it is failing when I deploy it on PCF.  It is seen that after sending a request to API B, API A keeps waiting for response and eventually time out.  I can see API B has received request, processed it and sent back the response.  Now, I am not sure why api A isn't really receiving given response and time out where given flow works perfect when deployed locally.

Comment: Did you tried to debug it on local by calling Service B(deployed on PCF) from service A running on local?

Comment: How is service-A looking up service-B? Are you using a service registry and lookup? Or have you hardcoded the urls (an antipattern for cloud)?

Comment: Also, have you hardcoded the ports? Your apps won't run on the same ports on PCF, as they do locally.

Comment: sorry for responding late... have just seen the queries... @Avhi yes... I have tried to debug it on local by calling Service B on pcf (from service A running locally)...but didn't find any clue... seems normal...  service A is referring service B by looking in to its endpoint hardcoded in env specific yml file.  When it comes to referring pcf url, it is different than local one where port isn't same and isn't hardcoded...